# Run Jquery again after the page loaded something new

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted my code to run again after some new data is being loaded into the page itself. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("page completed"); 
}
```

Once the page is loaded completely it will print `page completed` in the console. Is there any way to re-run the code when new things have been loaded into the page?

Case #1: On the Facebook news feed, when a user scrolls down the page, JavaScript is run to retrieve the new Facebook feeds and updates.

Case #2: Re-run the scripts when there's changes on the URL itself.

Comment: Put the code you need to execute in to a function, and call that function when you load the new content.

Comment: Putting it in a function is the tidy way of doing it, but you can also manually trigger any event handlers with `.trigger()`  (I'm not suggesting you do this - just informing you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your anonymous function with a normal function like this

```
function onDocumentReady() {
    // Your code
}
```

Then use that in `$(document).ready(onDocumentReady)` and later call it again where needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Bastiaanus' answer of having a common function, and assuming that your new content is loaded via jQuery's AJAX, you can configure a global handler to run some code every time some content is loaded, using [.ajaxSuccess()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).

If you want to handle more such events, refer to [this link](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).